# Convex combination of rational points

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry

Take $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$ points in $\mathbb{Q}^m \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, $n>m$, such that $0$ is in the interior of the convex hull $conv(p_1, \ldots, p_n)$.

Prove that exists $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\lambda_i \geq0$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i = 1$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i p_i = 0.$$

The answer is pretty clear for real coefficients, but I am having trouble trying to prove that exists rational coefficients.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565335/0-interior-to-the-convex-hull-of-rational-vectors